# Using Sqoop for Loading Oracle Data into Hadoop

Tags: oracle, sqoop

Hadoop is running on Cent OS in virtual machine. NAT and Bridge Adapters are enabled in VM. Oracle DB is installed in another node outside my VM. When I tried to ping the node where Oracle DB is installed from VM, its not going through. I am trying to import tables from Oracle DB to HDFS using Sqoop.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:SDBU/SDBU@192.168.100.154:1521/xe --table customers_fs --username SDBU --password SDBU --target-dir /sqoopOut_orcl -m 1
```

I am getting connection establishment error:

```
16/11/06 23:40:31 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
```

Please advise me on this.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: If you can't ping the node with the database, then it sounds more like a networking / VM config issue than anything to do with the database or JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the configuration issue you have or the firewall blocking from access, follow the below link it may help you,

[click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108878/how-to-connect-to-a-guest-vm-from-the-host-system)

Comment: Thanks very much, this is helpful.

Comment: Welcome Anuyogam :)

Answer (score 0):

ping 192.168.100.154 from your hadoop node. if ping fails then solve your connectivity issue first.

Comment: Yeah ping fails, I have solve the connectivity issue.